# Tinynav in WordPress Theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've added tinynav to a wordpress theme as a responsive menu. it outputs all of the menu info just fine however when selecting an option the page does not go the options value. Is there a way I can force this to work through jQuery, JavaScript?

TinyNav should have taken care of this but it must be conflicting with JS within the theme. I'm relatively poor at JS jQuery so any help is much appreciated.

the site is at http://cab9snowboarding.com/ just reduce the page size to see the menu.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: is this a WP plugin or did you install yourself? Either way, is there a place for you to define the url's to the pages you want them to go to? It looks like there are url's in the code but the drop-down box is not executing the choice being made... hmmmm

Comment: I see it's a plugin, I checked their support forum and no one seemed to have the same issue, maybe try uninstalling and re-installing the plugin?

Comment: Not a plugin, I installed this manually.

Comment: To make it into a working dropdown there will be some scripting involved.

Comment: I just took another look at your site and it seems like the dropdowns are working correctly now.  Did you make some changes?